# how create model class using gson of JsonArray where array is variable not constant android

Tags: android, json, gson

```
{
"801345": [{
    "type": "FOOTBALL",
    "name": "A",
    "id": "1"
}, {
    "type": "FOOTBALL",
    "name": "B",
    "id": "2"
},{
    "type": "CRICKET",
    "name": "C",
    "id": "3"
}, {
    "type": "VOLLEY",
    "name": "D",
    "id": "4"
}]
```

}

```
{
"910358": [{
    "type": "FOOTBALL",
    "name": "A",
    "id": "1"
}, {
    "type": "FOOTBALL",
    "name": "B",
    "id": "2"
},{
    "type": "CRICKET",
    "name": "C",
    "id": "3"
}, {
    "type": "VOLLEY",
    "name": "D",
    "id": "4"
}]
```

}

here team array is not constant it is variable. team is selected from dropdown and different Id for different team. How to create model class using variable array. team id are different like here 910358,801345

Comment: check this - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: how is this array variable. it seems constant to me and you can easily make a model out of it

Comment: Yor are right.In the field of team the the Json is returning different Id of team. I am editing my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) site for creating POJO class   http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Updates

I created a method for parsing this type json. try this

```
    private ArrayList<Teams> teamsJsonParsing(String json) throws JSONException {

          /*json="{\n" +
                "\"801345\": [{\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"FOOTBALL\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"A\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"1\"\n" +
                "}, {\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"FOOTBALL\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"B\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"2\"\n" +
                "},{\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"CRICKET\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"C\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"3\"\n" +
                "}, {\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"VOLLEY\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"D\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"4\"\n" +
                "}]\n" +
                ",\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\"910358\": [{\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"FOOTBALL\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"A\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"1\"\n" +
                "}, {\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"FOOTBALL\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"B\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"2\"\n" +
                "},{\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"CRICKET\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"C\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"3\"\n" +
                "}, {\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"VOLLEY\",\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"D\",\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"4\"\n" +
                "}]\n" +
                "}";
*/


        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(json);
        Iterator itr =jsonObject.keys();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        ArrayList<Teams> teamsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Object element = itr.next();
            Log.e("iterator",jsonObject.getJSONArray(element.toString()).toString());
            Teams teams=new Teams();
            teams.setTeamName(element.toString());
            ArrayList<Team> teamArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray(element.toString());
          for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
              Team team=gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(),Team.class);
              teamArrayList.add(team);
          }
          teams.setTeam(teamArrayList);
            teamsArrayList.add(teams);

        }
        return teamsArrayList;
    }
```

Example usage

```
 try {
        ArrayList<Teams> teamses= teamsJsonParsing(json);
        Log.e("team",teamses.size()+"");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your model classes are

```
 public class Team {

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

public class Teams {

   String teamName ;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    private List<Team> team = null;

    public List<Team> getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(List<Team> team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand your problem

Comment: I edited my answer. please try this. And let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

**Your Model Class Will be**

```
@SerializedName("team")
@Expose
private List<Team> team = null;

public List<Team> getTeam() {
  return team;
}

public void setTeam(List<Team> team) {
 this.team = team;
}
public class Team
{
      @SerializedName("type")
      @Expose
      private String type;


      @SerializedName("name")
      @Expose
      private String name;


      @SerializedName("id")
      @Expose
      private String id;


public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Comment: understand your concept but how can i parse the dynamic array as i edit my post above

Answer (score 0):

Your model class must be like this...

```
public class TeamListResponse {

    private List<Team> team;

    public List<Team> getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(List<Team> team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    private class Team{

        private String type,name,id;

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can i parse the dynamic array as i edit my post above.